# Getting HTTP 400 error as a Bad Request while ruuning JSP page

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, configuration

My Env variable :

```
CATALINA_HOME -> C:\Program Files\apache-tomcat-6.0.35
JAVA_HOME -> C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_03\bin
CLASSPATH -> .;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_03\bin;C:\Program Files\CVSNT\;
```

I am able to run localhost:8080 from browser(firefox),unable to run the same from eclipse.
Showing "The webpage cannot be found .... HTTP 400"

```
Moreover In my eclipse, catalina.home and catalina.base are use same i.e. "Servers/Tomcat v6.0 Server at localhost.server" and "Use Tomcat Installation".
```

When I am trying to run my project in eclipse localhost(http://localhost:8080/MyProject/JSP/abc.jsp) it still showing Error 400 and in firefox it is showing only a blank page,but my code is right.

kindly tell Where I am going wrong....

Comment: 404 means page is not there. Could be that you URL is not correct or the server is not properly started.

Comment: @jddsantaella, yes my page is not there...(neither http://localhost:8080/MyProject/JSP/abc.jsp nor http://localhost:8080)